# multiple count in a sql query

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

i need a report from a database where i need the final result like
Number of Male, Number of Female, showing against city and finally against State.
I  started off with something like.

```
SELECT     p.StateName,  d.CityName,
 count(api.Gender) as Gender
FROM       dbo.Application_Personal_information as api INNER JOIN
           dbo.state as p ON api.State = p.ID INNER JOIN
           dbo.City as d ON api.City= d.ID
           group by p.StateName, d.CityName
```

when i do this

```
   SELECT     p.StateName,  d.CityName,
     count(api.Gender = 'Male) as Male,
     count(api.Gender = 'Female) as Female,
    FROM       dbo.Application_Personal_information as api INNER JOIN
               dbo.state as p ON api.State = p.ID INNER JOIN
               dbo.City as d ON api.City= d.ID
               group by p.StateName, d.CityName
```

it give's me error.
incorrect syntax near =.
i also tried with select statement

```
 COUNT(select api.Gender from api where api.Gender ='Male') as Male,
```

But it is also not working.
...
Any idea?

Comment: See answer below: if you need the output to be exactly as you showed it, it's slightly more tricky.

Answer (score 4):

```
SELECT     
    p.StateName,  d.CityName, 
    sum(case when Gender ='Male' then 1 else 0 end ) as Male_count,
    sum(case when Gender ='Female' then 1 else 0 end ) as Female_count

FROM
    dbo.Application_Personal_information as api INNER JOIN 
    dbo.state as p ON api.State = p.ID INNER JOIN 
    dbo.City as d ON api.City= d.ID 
group by 
    p.StateName, d.CityName
```

Comment: This works too - but I suspect it will be much slower - speed may not be an issue here though.

Comment: `SUM(Gender ='Male')` works too in MySQL (because `TRUE` is `1` and `FALSE` is `0`)

Comment: Thats good ypercube. But it is more generic to MySQL and sometimes may be confuse you :)

Comment: Yes, your query is more db-agnostic. ( I really thought this was tagged with MySQL, was it?). I prefer `COUNT()` over `SUM()` but I don't think there is any performance difference: `COUNT(CASE WHEN Gender ='Male' THEN 1 ELSE NULL END)`

Comment: But won't you get warning about NULL values when you use COUNT over SUM?

Answer (score 4):

You could try the PIVOT function if you are using SQL Server 2005 or later:

```
WITH CTE AS
(   SELECT  p.StateName,  
            d.CityName,
            api.Gender
    FROM    dbo.Application_Personal_information as api 
            INNER JOIN dbo.state as p 
                ON api.State = p.ID 
            INNER JOIN dbo.City as d 
                ON api.City= d.ID
)
SELECT  *
FROM    CTE
        PIVOT
        (   COUNT(Gender)
            FOR Gender IN ([Male], [Female])
        ) pvt
```

Comment: PIVOT was introduced in version 2005 :)